# Override standard translation function in ZF2

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, overriding

Can I override standard `translate` function in ZF2, includes form translations?
In current state, I have done this only with view helper by replacing `$this->translate()` method by my own, so how I can do the same globally (with form builder (labels, select values, etc.) and others)? 
Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

You could extend the `Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator` with your class and override the `translate` method.

Then you could just replace in the service manager the usual `translator` service with your own, defining in configuration a service corresponding with the `translator` key

Comment: Where I can add the override translate method? Can i have any example to override default core translator?